# Counting in JBuilder throw exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

`json.votes answer, answer.votes.count` throw `0 is not a symbol nor a string`

Also try 
`json.votes answer, answer.votes.count.to_s` throw `undefined method '0' for #<Answer:0x00000004699a98>`

[Application code](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/poller/blob/master/app/views/polls/_answer.json.jbuilder#L2)

Comment: Is there any question here ? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `json.votes answer.votes.count`